# fill AutoCompleteTextView using BaseAdapter android

Tags: android

can someone please give me an link of filling AutoCompleteTextView using  BaseAdapter in android for phone contacts.

Thanks

Comment: can you help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29046302/how-to-implement-autocompletetextview-with-listview

Answer (score 11, accepted):

user750716 is wrong.
You can fill AutoCompleteTextView with BaseAdapter. You just need to remember that BaseAdapter has to implement Filterable.

In Adapter create your ArrayList of Objects.
Implement getView with whatever View you want and fill it with objects.get(position) info.
Implement getItem(int position) returning a string (name of clicked object)

In the same adapter add stuff for filtering:

```
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new MyFilter();
}

private class MyFilter extends Filter {

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence filterString) {
        // this will be done in different thread 
        // so you could even download this data from internet

        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

        ArrayList<myObject> allMatching = new ArrayList<myObject>()

        // find all matching objects here and add 
        // them to allMatching, use filterString.

        results.values = allMatching;
        results.count = allMatching.size();

        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        objects.clear();

        ArrayList<myObject> allMatching = (ArrayList<myObject>) results.values;
        if (allMatching != null && !allMatching.isEmpty()) {
            objects = allMatching;
        }

        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks glad to get an answer after a long time.

Comment: can you help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29046302/how-to-implement-autocompletetextview-with-listview

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with an BaseAdapter but you can use a CursorAdapter with no SQLite DB in the background. In the function runQueryOnBackgroundThread you can create an MatrixCursor. 
Something like this:

```
   String[] tableCols = new String[] { "_id", "keyword" };
   MatrixCursor cursor = new MatrixCursor(tableCols);
   cursor.addRow(new Object[] { 1, "went" });
   cursor.addRow(new Object[] { 2, "gone" });
```

I have done this in my morphological analyzer.